# Does the US National Weather Service use Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Tags: meteorology, temperature

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/NWSLaCrosse/status/1090571778139832320/photo/1) from the National Weather Service in LaCrosse, Wisconsin, USA says:

> We have officially hit -30 here at the NWS La Crosse office as of 520 a.m. The wind chill is -54. Be sure to dress appropriately if you're heading out for the day.

The photo shown below shows a digital readout of an electronic thermometer, showing -30.1 but has no units. The -30's are getting close to where the Celsius and Fahrenheit scales tend to have similar numerical values, so there's no way to use context in this case to choose the most likely answer. No units are shown on the front panel, and [these instructions](https://www.weather.gov/media/box/coop/coop_nimbus_instructions.pdf) offer no help either.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "Centigrade"  It's "Celsius" .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft [Centigrade, a historical forerunner to the Celsius temperature scale, **synonymous in modern usage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centigrade) also [The centigrade scale is essentially identical to the Celsius scale, the standard scale by which temperature is measured in most of the world.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centigrade)

Comment: All the weather forecast models that I know of in the NWS are run in degrees Kelvin and then the temperature is transform into either Fahrenheit or Celsius.

Comment: @uhoh OK but the name "Celsius" was adopted more than 70 years ago.

Comment: Adopted more than 70 years ago? My elementary school teachers in the 1990s US must have missed the memo. It's still widely understood, at least in the US. Centigrade = Celsius; the big C.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I wonder if a new question about that somewhere might be a good idea. I've seen some equivocation: [Did You Know?
The centigrade scale is ***essentially identical*** to the Celsius scale...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centigrade) like they don't want to quite say it is *exactly equal to*. If they are both linear and share the same endpoints, I can't see how they couldn't be exactly equal. Why not ask? ("enquiring minds want to know!")

Comment: Guess it might be on topic at the history of science SE, if someone were interested. Unfortunately that would not include me.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas [When and how did usage of the term Centigrade give way to Celsius? Are/were they in fact numerically identical?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8266/3869) "But in his version, 100° marked the freezing point of water..." *Your peas used to freeze at a hundred degrees!*

Comment: @uhoh The tweet says that the wind chill is -54, and it's unlikely for the wind (even for the strong one) to lower the "feel-like" temperature by 24°C. On the other side, 24°F (about 13.3°C) difference is reasonable (but the wind still has to be quite strong).

Comment: @trolley813 excellent, "science rules!"

Comment: @arkaia The readout definitely isn't in Kelvin.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas FWIW, older folk in the UK will still use the term, though it's less common as age decreases

Comment: @gansub I thought Mast was being humorous; trolley813 made a deduction from the wind chill, so I thought Mast was taking "deductionism" a step beyond and remarking that it couldn't be Kelvin (simply because the number is negative).

Comment: @uhoh got it ! Back to the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[NWS Temperature forecast](https://graphical.weather.gov/sectors/conus.php?element=T) or [new forecast](https://digital.weather.gov/)

From these URLs, it  appears that the unit is Fahrenheit.

and if you click on this URL - [Max/MinT](https://graphical.weather.gov/definitions/defineMaxMinT.html)

> Is the maximum daytime or minimum overnight temperature in degrees Fahrenheit.

In the USA  NWS always used to issue forecasts and bulletins in Fahrenheit and some background can be obtained from here [US Customary Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units) and here - [Why Americans still use Fahrenheit](https://www.vox.com/2015/2/16/8031177/america-fahrenheit) as well here - [Fahrenheit Versus Celsius: Why the US Hasn't Converted](https://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-glossary/fahrenheit-versus-celsius-why/17969960)

> Degrees Fahrenheit are used in the U.S. to measure temperatures in most non-scientific contexts. The Rankine scale of absolute temperature also saw some use in thermodynamics. Scientists worldwide use the kelvin and degree Celsius. Several U.S. technical standards are expressed in Fahrenheit temperatures and American medical practitioners often use degrees Fahrenheit for body temperature.

In reality, the NWS and [NCDC](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/) weather forecast model outputs for the different systems ([GFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Forecast_System), [NAM](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/north-american-mesoscale-forecast-system-nam), [NARR](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/north-american-regional-reanalysis-narr)...) use temperatures in Kelvin. This satisfies the international standards (e.g., CF1.6 convention compliant) and also avoids issues with advecting fields (in this case) that are equal to zero in some locations. You can see this if you look at the model output directly (for instance, [here](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/gfs-g4-anl-files/201901/20190126/gfsanl_4_20190126_0000_006.grb2.html) or [here](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/gfs-g4-anl-files/201901/catalog.html)). Afterward, in post-processing the temperature is transformed to either Celsius or more commonly Fahrenheit for public consumption.

Scientists and meteorological researchers are more used to Kelvin and/or degrees Celsius.

Comment: Rankine! https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14456/12102

Comment: I haven't been in the US in quite a while, I'd actually forgotten that the government still uses F. My goodness.

Comment: @uhoh It's the US scientists whom I feel sorry for - they have to work in Kelvin or Centigrade, but have to go through daily life in F.

Comment: @UKMonkey but Fahrenheit is so much better for daily life, the range of temperatures is just about 0 to 100, at least where I live, instead of -18 to 38

Comment: @StephenS As a general rule, the only part of the number (in Celsius) I care about in my "daily life" is is there a minus sign in the forecast - ie is there a reasonable chance for ice.  It's literally impossible for someone to tell me the temperature here without highlighting if the roads and pavements will be dangerous.  I would say for daily life, C is still better.

Comment: @UKMonkey agreeing with you that Celsius is better. In the place where I live (Russia) the range of temperatures is about -35° to 35°C (-31° to 97°F), even symmetrical around the zero. And the temperature of 35°C, either plus or minus (it's interesting that in Russia the plus sign usually is explicitly written when the temperature is positive, e.g. +18°C instead of 18°C), does indicate near-extreme weather conditions. And of course, negative number means frost and ice.

Answer (score 15):

## That device only shows Fahrenheit

I don't know about the full Weather Service, but that device only shows Fahrenheit measurements. You can see this in the [user manual](https://www.weather.gov/media/ind/nimbus_manual.pdf), in the appendix, page 18
[image]

Comment: Excellent, here I'd thought that the [Nimbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch#Broomsticks) was a broomstick.

Comment: I love the alternative way of getting to the answer, but the third line does say that °C is a factory option, so it is at least _conceivable_ it was showing Celsius.

Comment: The image actually shows the opposite of what you claim. It shows that it can be set of oC at the factory.

Comment: @ikegami good catch!